# OIDC, Rest API and vue.js client

Tags: spring, rest, openid-connect

I need to create a REST API (with Springboot) that is consumed by a web client written with vue.js. The authentication must be made with OpenId Connect and the authorization code flow. My company has its own OIDC provider and my question is how can I implements this flow.

I first saw the [oidc-client-js](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/) library that perfoms everything i need except that it is fully client side and the security of my company does not allow it.

Secondly I saw this [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-openid-connect) (source code availlable [here](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/spring-security-modules/spring-security-oidc)), what i understand is that spring handles everything for you as long as the configuration is ok. But what I do not understand is how the token is provided to the client ?

Does someone has any further explaination on this mechanism ? Or am I simply misleaded ?

Thanx for your answer.